# Stream video from php server to android programmatically

Tags: php, android, video, stream

I have a url to a video. I want to stream the video to my application. I can download the video file completely and then play it but i want that while downloading the video the video should also be played, like in youtube. I have a php server running which has the video on it. 
I have seen this question being asked but there were no answers for any of the questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go through code

```
void playvideo(String url) 
{
     String  link=url;
     Log.e("url",link);
     view1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView); 
      getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

      MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
      mc.setMediaPlayer(view1); 

      view1.setMediaController(mc); 
      view1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(link)); 
      view1.requestFocus(); 
      view1.start();

 }
```

Comment: The link is broken please update it. I have fine with Android part, how to do this in PHP on server side

Comment: this helped @Nirali one more thing the play paus and progress bar of the videoview is shown outside the video view, how to get that under the videoview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an .mp4 container or similar, you need to use a program such as `qt-faststart` (under linux) to move the moov atom (containing data on keyframes etc., I believe) to the begining of the video. That way the video can play prior to the whole video being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

your video file may not be set up for progressive download, which is required for HTTP streaming