# Why the services are not starting in my case?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android and I'm trying to understand the service.

My manifest file looks:

```
    <!--The invoice launcher service-->
    <service android:process=":invoice_background"
             android:name="InvoiceManagerService"
             android:label="invoice_service" />

    <!--The receiver-->
    <receiver android:name="InvoiceStartupReceiver"
              android:process=":invoice_background">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My service looks like :

```
public class InvoiceManagerService extends Service {

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my receiver looks like:

```
public class InvoiceStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent invoiceService = new Intent(context, InvoiceManagerService.class);
        context.startService(invoiceService);


    }
}
```

My app is getting executed without any error. But no services been created! Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1/ do you have the permission to receive the boot_completed broadcast ? 2/ do you reboot your phone ? 3/ what can you see in the logcat ?

Comment: @njzk2: I'm testing out in my emulator. And in the logcat I don't see any logs which says that my service is been started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm very new to Android

Because of this sentence I suggest you use an `IntentService` instead of `Service` as IntentService is much easier to use. I wrote some basic code for another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835601/androidhow-to-create-a-button-to-get-file-from-the-web/14837545#14837545) where the person wanted to download a file and then inform the Activity this had happened. It will show you proper use of the IntentService and how to call the task is finished.